# Colorbox with wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, colorbox

Hi I want to install colorbox  inside my wordpress site. I dont need any plugin I want to install it manually how can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activate the plugin, view source to see what needs to load, add those JS and CSS calls manually to header.php. Or simply look at the Colorbox docs for installation and add JS and CSS calls to header.php and markup in the html.